# Node in private mode and archive storage connected to public node in full storage will ever be synced?

Tags: private-mode, public-node

My question is:

- public node A, full storage mode (imported from snapshot)
- private node B, archive storage type
- B is connected to A, starting from scratch

Will B node receive from A all the context from the origin even if the two nodes are not the same storage type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a full node contains all the data necessary to participate to the network as a bootstrap peer (namely all the blocks of the chain), it is indeed possible to bootstrap a node (archive, full or rolling) from a full node.

Only the rolling nodes cannot participate to the whole bootstrap effort as they don't recall the complete chain, but only a small rolling window.

Comment: But if I am not mistaken, the full mode has the context of the blocks from where the snapshot has been taken, so the previous contexts are not know to the full node. Am I wrong?

Comment: For reference http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/history_modes.html

Comment: You are not wrong. Full nodes do not store all the contexts (unlike the archive nodes). However, only the blocks (mainly headers + operation) are needed to bootstrap a node as the context is made of the result of the successive application of all the blocks from the genesis -- blocks that can be shared by full nodes. Contexts are never transmitted between peers as it can be computed locally. To do so, a block header at level `N` and its corresponding operations are "applied" on top of the context `N-1` to compute context at level `N`.

Answer (score 1):

I might have found the answer from [this blog post from Nomadic Labs](https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/introducing-snapshots-and-history-modes-for-the-tezos-node.html):

> An important thing to note is that running a full node is enough to maintain the full chain history. Indeed, **archive nodes do not need to use archive peers to bootstrap their archive, but only full peers**, as the chain data is enough to apply the chain and construct the context archives. In other words, the network does not lose any security by switching to full as the default.